# Flutter Widgets quick quiz The Flutter Framework

Tags: flutter, widget

**Can you please fill the ??? area for me.Im learning flutter and i think some of my answers are wrong.I wrote my answer after the "???"**

**QUESTİON 1 OF 2**
*The available answers to place are : Opacity, Checkbox, Slider, GridView, Dropdown, Padding, MaterialApp*

**For each scenario, pick a Widget that can accomplish the task:**

I want to make a volume control for my app ----> ????  My answer was: Slider

I have a large number of photos that I want the user to scroll through, efficiently ----> ????  My answer was: GridView

I’m making a form and want a user to select all the types of music they listen to, from a list ----> ????  My answer was: Dropdown

I want the user to choose the month of their birthday from a list ----> ????  My answer was: Checkbox

I want to make a nice semi-transparent lightbox that overlays my app screen ----> ????  My answer was: MaterialApp

**QUESTİON 2 OF 2
For each scenario, pick a Widget that can accomplish the task:**

*The available answers to place are : Padding, Center, Flex, Stack, Align, MateriallApp, GestureDetector*

TASK
WİDGET

All I want to do is center this image on the screen! ----> ????  My answer was: Center

I have three Containers, and I want them to always each take up a third of the screen. ----> ????  My answer was: Stack

I want the Submit button to always be at the top right of the screen. ----> ????  My answer was: Align

I want a sticky footer at the bottom of my app that is always visible, laying "on top of" the other widgets on the page ----> ????  My answer was: Align

I want a Widget to perform an action when I swipe left* ----> ????  My answer was: GestureDetector

> Some of my answers are wrong and because of that i got really curious and  instead of checking each one on the web i preferred to ask here.Hope someone quickly notices the wrong ones.

Comment: We don't do well on hypothetical problems. We don't know what the creator of the quiz deems correct. Do your answers work? Did you try it out?

Comment: they don't work it just returns me "Try again"  and it doesn't show which one is correct or false. If you think i can't get help with the way it's been asked, i can delete it and try to find on the documents. I asked here so can continue learning.

Comment: A quiz that does not tell you what is wrong and what would be the correct answer and why is not a learning resource, it's just that... a pop quiz. Go find a good learning resource instead of a pop quiz.

Comment: I Added the choices the creator put there to pick from.

Quiz is from flutter's official learning documents. from here ---->https://classroom.udacity.com/courses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is:

1)

- Slider
- GridView
- Checkbox (List of checkboxes)
- Dropdown
- Opacity (make transparent)

2. 

- Center
- Flex
- Align
- Stack ("on top of")
- GestureDetector